# Why would this SQLite query return false?

Tags: c#, sqlite, arguments

I've got a general-purpose method that should be useful for seeing if at least one record with a given value exists in a given column in a given table. But when I call it like this:

```
return ColumnInTableContainsStrValue("Inventory", "siteNum", NRBQConsts.currentSiteNum);
```

...it returns false, even though the table does contain records where the "siteNum" column is "03". Here is the method in question:

```
public bool ColumnInTableContainsStrValue(String tableName, String 
columnName, String valToFind)
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached
TestHHSDBUtils.ColumnInTableContainsStrValue");
    int count;
    string qry = String.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0} WHERE {1} = 
@soughtValue", tableName, columnName)
    // TODO: temp - remove
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("In ColumnInTableContainsStrValue; qry 
== {0}; valToFind == {1}", qry, valToFind));

    try
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection con = new 
SQLiteConnection(HHSUtils.GetDBConnection()))
        {
            con.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(qry, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("soughtValue", 
valToFind));
            count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String msgInnerExAndStackTrace = String.Format(
            "{0}; Inner Ex: {1}; Stack Trace: {2}", ex.Message, 
ex.InnerException, ex.StackTrace);
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(String.Format("From 
TestHHSDBUtils.ColumnInTableContainsStrValue: {0}", 
msgInnerExAndStackTrace));
        return false;
    }
    return count > 0;
}
```

The temporary MessageBox.Show() call that I have in the method above shows:

[image]

So once the query arg gets converted from @soughtValue to valToFind ("03"), the query should be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Inventory WHERE siteNum = "03"
```

The query above does work as expected in LINQPad:

[image]

So why is it failing in "real life"?

**Note:** the catch block in ColumnInTableContainsStrValue() catches nothing - there is nothing in the log file diesbzg.

### UPDATE

After changing the catch block to catch SQLiteException (in place of the generic Exception), I got this:

*Date: 4/8/2009 10:01:28 PM
Message: From frmMain.ProcessNewDelivery: InvalidCastException; Inner Ex: ; Stack Trace:    at HHS.TestHHSDBUtils.ColumnInTableContainsStrValue(String tableName, String columnName, String valToFind)
   at HHS.frmMain.SiteInventoryHasBeenFetched()
   at HHS.frmMain.ProcessNewDelivery()
   at HHS.frmMain.menuItemFILE_NewDelivery_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Menu.ProcessMnuProc(Control ctlThis, WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
   at HHS.Program.Main()*

Maybe I have to encase the arg in quotes?

Comment: Since you are using LINQPad, you can also check the sql statement being queried in the SQL tab, without having to use msgbox.

Comment: That's what you see above, at the end of my post.

Comment: Try to use a long variable for count and cast to long. I wonder why this doesn't throw an Invalid Cast Exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLite the result from `ExecuteScalar` is an `Int64`.
So technically your query should fail with an `Invalid Cast Exception` (both in 'real life' and in LinqPad)

You could verify this changing your call to `ExecuteScalar` to

```
 object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 result.GetType().Dump();
```

So, you simply need to change the datatype of `count` to be a long and cast the return value from ExecuteScalar to a long.
The reason why you don't see anything in your log file remains a mistery.

Comment: Cool; that, and reverting to my original string.formatted() query statement, and it works!